# How to authenticate the administrator username in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I want to authenticate the administrator username's password.
The **administrator** username is not a domain account but a **local** system account.
 
I am trying to do this in Python, but any code even if it is .NET, VC++ would be fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) (and be sure to CloseHandle after) or call [NetUserChangePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370650(v=VS.85).aspx) (with old and new passwords the same). Anything in .NET or Python will likely wrap LogonUser.

Comment: Thanks. Python has the Pywin32 module which supports the LogonUser function and it worked.